# How do I merge changes from a squashed commit in master without encountering spurious conflicts?

Tags: git, branch, branching-and-merging

This is really a **git** question; Azure DevOps is only relevant because it does the squashing for us, which is nice.

In Azure DevOps, my team and I often do a merge on a pull request completion with a "squash commit" per the screenshot below.  This understandably creates a new commit in master on merge.

However, this new commit creates spurious merge conflicts in any other existing branch that came from that branch.  I'd like often to create a new branch B from branch A, then merge (via a squash commit) branch A into master, **then merge master into branch B without encountering old "conflicts" that aren't really conflicts** because they were already in branch A when I created my branch B.  **Any idea how?**

I tried to rebase, but that doesn't address my problem...it seems like I still have to examine every conflict and resolve them.

Obviously Git doesn't know that the squash commit is related to the log of branch B, but usually I know that the commit is there and any conflicts can be resolved by taking the incoming version.  (Of course, I may have unrelated conflicts due to changes in branch B, but those are to be expected!)

Here's the Azure DevOps UI that results in this new squashed commit, for reference.
[image]

Comment: How about _not_ squashing?

Comment: That creates a really messy history that I fear would quickly become too onerous to browse.  Have thought about it, though.

Comment: The short answer is "you don't, at least, not automatically" and that's why squashing can be bad. To solve the "squashing is bad" problem when you consider squashing desirable, treat any squashed-in branch as "dead": never do anything else with it, just delete it immediately.

Comment: In your particular case, I assume you have a branch `branch-B` that adds commits on to those commits in `branch-A`. In this case, just before deleting `branch-A`, *rebase* your `branch-B` commits `--onto` the main branch (into which the other commits were squashed) using `branch-A` as the cutoff for which commits should be copied, so that you copy the existing `branch-B` commits atop the squashed commit. This is a little tricky, but once you get the pattern, it's easy enough to do.

Comment: Note that squashing isn't causing the problem by itself. Any rewrite to branch A (rebase or amend) after branch B branched off of A would cause the same problem. In general you should try to avoid having B branch off of A whenever possible, and instead have everyone branch off of master. In the (hopefully rare) case when you do have to branch B off of A before A goes into master, then I agree with torek: use rebase with the --onto option to rebase only the specific commit range in B.

Comment: This seems like one of the most common use cases for pull requests--I need to keep working (in B) while I wait for the PR of A to be finished.  Why should branching off a feature branch be rare at all?

Answer (score 0):

One possible policy when having branches that depend on one another is :

- when branch `A` gets merged to master, manually rebase all branches that forked from `A` onto the new `master` (which now includes `A`)

---

For your `B` branch, this would mean :

- spot the fork point between `B` and `A` (commit `y` in the diagram below)
- spot the commit that "merged" `A` into `master` (commit `M` in the diagram below)

Rebasing `B` on `M` would be :

```sh
# a visual of your history :
             <new A> : merge A into master
                  v
*--x--*--*--*--*--M--* <- master
    \
     *--*--y--*--*--* <- A
           ^\
           | *--*--*--*--* <- B
           |
     <base B> : fork point between A and B

# to rebase 'only the commits of branch B', run :
git rebase --onto <M> <y> B
```

---

What you gain :

- the scope of the conflicts will be smaller : instead of comparing the diffs that occurred since `x` (the fork point of `A`), git will only inspect diffs that occurred since `y`

What you still have to handle :

- incompatible changes on master : if you had to fix conflicts when merging `A`, chances are you will hit some related conflicts again when replaying `B` on top of `M`